# Objective c Bool always NO

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Alright, my mistake, I had previously believed that my ivar was not changing correctly.  I was wrong (and got a few downvotes for it).  Sorry, the real issue is that i've been calling it incorrectly.  I am now posting all the code and i'll let you look at it.

My First class:

classOne.h:

```
@interface DetailPageController : UIPageViewController
{

    BOOL isChromeHidden_;

}

- (void)toggleChromeDisplay;


@end
```

classOne.m:

```
@interface DetailPageController ()

@end

@implementation DetailPageController

- (void)toggleChromeDisplay
{
    [self toggleChrome:!isChromeHidden_];
}

- (void)toggleChrome:(BOOL)hide
{
    //Find chrome value
    isChromeHidden_ = !isChromeHidden_;
    NSLog(isChromeHidden_ ? @"YES" : @"NO");     

}

@end
```

From the comment's I have received I believe none of that is the actual issue, it's in the following.

classTwo.h: (nothing declared)

classTwo.m:

```
@interface classTwo ()


@end

@implementation classTwo

//Touches Control
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch view]) {
        if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
            NSLog(@"double touched");
            [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(toggleChromeDisplay) object:nil];
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch view]) {
        if ([touch tapCount] == 1) {
            NSLog(@"single touch");
            [self performSelector:@selector(toggleChromeDisplay) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
        }
    }
}

- (void)toggleChromeDisplay
{

    DetailPageController *pageController = [[DetailPageController alloc] init];
    [pageController toggleChromeDisplay];
}

@end
```

Again, sorry for the previous post, I had thought it was an issue with the method but is in fact the way I am calling it.

What I have been forced to do is implement the touching in the controller which handles the area touched but I have the method for the chrome (nav bar and toolbar) in another.

**Overall Question** 
Why is it that every time I call my toggleChromeDisplay method in classTwo, I always get the same NO from my ivar in classOne?

What i've tried for classTwo.h:

```
#import "DetailPageController.h"

@interface classTwo : UIViewController
{
    DetailPageController *detailPageController_;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) DetailPageController *detailPageController;

@end
```

---

My modified code:

In my classTwo.h:

```
#import "DetailPageController.h"

@interface PhotoViewController : UIViewController
{
    DetailPageController *detailPageController_;
}



@property (nonatomic, strong) DetailPageController *detailPageController;

@end
```

classTwo.m:

```
#import "classTwo.h"

@interface classTwo ()

@end

@implementation classTwo

@synthesize detailPageController = detailPageController_;

//Touches Control
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch view]) {
        if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
            NSLog(@"double touched");
            [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(toggleChromeDisplay) object:nil];
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch view]) {
        if ([touch tapCount] == 1) {
            NSLog(@"single touch");
            [self performSelector:@selector(toggleChromeDisplay) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
        }
    }
}

- (void)toggleChromeDisplay
{
    [self.detailPageController toggleChromeDisplay];
}

@end
```

Comment: "Shouldn't every time toggleChrome is called the BOOL value should be different?" - why should it?

Comment: It would be set to whatever the value of hide is.  Can you include the code where you're calling this method?

Comment: Where are you calling `toggleChrome:` from? Are you passing a different value for `hide` each time? Whatever value you pass in `hide` is being stored in `isChromeHidden_`

Comment: isChromeHidden_ = !isChromeHidden_ will toggle it

Comment: To truly toggle you should do:  isChromeHidden_ = !isChromeHidden_.  No need to pass the hide variable if you want to toggle.

Comment: I updated it, also no need for the down vote.  I simply missed adding some code.

Comment: Some confusion is being caused by your function name "toggleChrome" which does not actually toggle, it just sets.

Comment: I mean I can delete all the code if thats confusing.

Comment: Is there a question??

Comment: Updated it just for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`classTwo` always instantiates a completely **brand new** instance of `DetailPageViewController` before calling `toggleChromeDisplay` on it, and then it allows it to go out of scope and presumably is deallocated. You need to have it use an instance that's actually alive in your program and controls views in the view hierarchy.

You could add a `DetailPageViewController` property to `classTwo` and then your `-[classTwo toggleChromeDisplay]` implementation would look like:

```
- (void)toggleChromeDisplay
{
    [self.detailPageController toggleChromeDisplay];
}
```

Again, just make sure to assign to that property the instance of the view controller that's actually on screen. `alloc` and `init` are used to creating brand new instances of objects, which won't be the ones that already exist in your application if they've been loaded up, for instance, from a storyboard. So, in your application you probably have a `DetailPageViewController` instance already that is doing things on the screen and controlling interactions with the user - but your `classTwo` never is able to message it because again it's creating entirely separate instances of that class. So you need to determine where in your application the `DetailPageViewController` that's visible on screen is getting instantiated, and at that point ensure your `classTwo` instance can get a reference to it.

Forgive my repetitiveness, but it is a common mistake I see on Stack Overflow. Just make sure that you understand that while there is one definition of a Class, which is where its instance variables and methods are defined, there can be many separate instances of objects that are created from it (we often say they are instantiated, or created, `init`ed, you'll see a number of terms). Each of those objects can have different values for their instance variables (and properties), and they all have their own distinct life time from a memory-management standpoint. Calling the pair of methods `alloc` and `init` is one very common way to make a new instance of a class, that has its own lifetime and instance variables.

Finally, I'd like to suggest that you read and follow Apple's [Cocoa style guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) as your choice of names for methods and classes has caused confusion among your fellow developers. If you start to apply that you will find communication with others to go smoother and your problems easier to understand.

Comment: You've been very helpful, i'm sure i'll figure out why I am having issues calling it.

Comment: Probably just a issue with me being a beginner.

Comment: We've all been beginners :) Let me know if I can clarify any points in this answer further.

Comment: Your answer is pretty clear, is this how you'd assign to the property the instance variable of the view controller on screen (classTwo is on screen)?  Code posted above.

Comment: No you'd want it to be strong or retain (the latter if you're not using ARC)

Comment: Yes I am using ARC, and I went ahead and posted some more code at the bottom if you would want to look at it, for some reason it is still not calling it, they must not be connected correctly right?

Comment: @lostAstronaut If you didn't find the DetailPageController instance and assign it to the property, then no, they are not connected correctly.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is

```
- (void)toggleChromeDisplay
{
    isChromeHidden_ = !isChromeHidden_;
}
```

(based on your edit)

Answer (score 1):

toggleChrome: *sets* the `isChromeHidden_` variable, it does not *toggle* it. To toggle you would write:

```
- (void)toggleChrome
{
    isChromeHidden_ = !isChromeHidden_;

    //Find chrome value
    NSLog(isChromeHidden_ ? @"YES" : @"NO");
}
```

!isChromeHidden_ is the opposite value of isChromeHidden_.

Comment: Gotcha, still my example is the proper way to write a toggle method. When you are passing a variable in, you are actually *setting* the variable, which could be anything you pass in. Toggling already knows how to find what value to use and so is much less prone to bugs.

Comment: Then if i'd be to call it later, ie the user touches again would it change?

Comment: Also I need to pass (BOOL)hide because I have other methods that may need to send YES regardless of the current value.

Comment: Then it isn't a toggle, its a setter. Nothing wrong with it necessarily, just follow conventions.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your exact code into my project and it is switching between YES and NO as expected. This tells me that your code that you have posted is in fact correct and you are either calling it incorrectly or you are setting the variable somewhere else as well.

Comment: Yea, thats what i'm beginning to believe